Ubuntu 24.04.1 boots into emergency mode after upgrade
I have always had problems when upgrading Ubuntu so I avoid doing it. However, a friend said he never has a problem with it so I decided to give a go this morning - I almost wish I hadn't bothered.
So, I have just upgraded to 24.04.1 and when the system reboots it just shows a black screen with a flashing cursor in the top left corner.
If I press some keys I can find emergency mode where I can read the boot log but it's so full of cruft I have no idea how to start diagnosing the problem.
I'm know a lot of work has gone into the latest version - so it seems a shame to give up on the upgrade process and just reinstall Ubuntu (which I have always done in the past - and I suspect is what most people would do in this situation).
Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Try the following:
In the terminal run:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt -m install
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot

If any command gives an error, repeat the series of commands several times.

Thanks for the suggestion - what is the problem that this fixes?

man apt -- man dpkg

... and thanks for the explanation.

Thanks to kyodake's suggestion ubuntu is working again. I had to reboot in recovery mode to get networking first (networking doesn't seem to be enabled in emergency mode) - and then hit ctrl-d a few times to kill the shell that was grabbing keyboard input from the recovery mode menu.
I would be interested to know why this was necessary - it's a really poor user experience - why doesn't upgrading ubuntu just work by clicking the button in the GUI?
